# active_admin application using existing database

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am developing active_admin application using existing database.
Where I am having table SUIUBI which I wanted to replace with active_admin table.
In short I need SUIUBI table instead active_admin
So can I remove active_admin table & use SUIUBI table?

SUIUBI table having following fields

```
 :UBIREFNUM, :UBIFNAME, :UBILNAME, :UBIEMAILID, :UBIMOBNUM, :UBITELNUM, :UBICITY, :UBIADD, :UBIDEPT,:UBIPASSWORD, :UBICREATEDDATE, :UBICREATEDBY, :UBIMODIFIEDDATE, :UBIMODIFIEDBY, :UBIISACTIVE, :email, :encrypted_password
```

Is there any drawback of doing this?
What changes should I do for doing this?

And one more thing My database is not as per naming conversion So is this create problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you are asking here, but maybe you want to inject the existing model into active admin so it shows the related datas in the index page?
If your table is linked to a model, you can just run:

```
rails g active_admin:resource SUIUBI
```

---

I hope i have been helpful,
Regards,

Marin

Comment: I wanted to replace adctive_admin resource with SUIUBI resorce